# What is the expectation of a normally-distributed random variable raised to a (positive, non-integer) power?

Tags: integration, functions, expected-value

Let $x$ be a normally-distributed random variable, $x \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Denote its PDF $\phi(x)$.

Let $g(x)$ be the function $g(x) = x^{\lambda}$, where $\lambda > 1$ is a non-integer positive constant.

What is the value of the expectation $E[g(x)] = \int{g(x)\phi(x)dx} $?

Every resource I search through provides solutions for positive integer values of $\lambda$ by evaluating the MGF of $x$; I have yet to find a clear solution for non-integer values.

Thank you!

Comment: Make the substitution $u = x^2$; you'll get the answer in terms of the Gamma function.

Comment: Thanks @QiaochuYuan . Could you elaborate a bit further? Do you mean substitute $u = x^\lambda$ ?

Comment: No, I mean $u = x^2$. This simplifies the $- \frac{x^2}{2 \sigma}$ in the exponent of $\phi(x)$ and then you can see the Gamma integral show up.

Comment: Thanks. So if I'm understanding correctly, your solution would involve transforming the normally-distributed r.v. $x$ to a standard normal r.v. (call it $z$) where the exponent of the PDF $phi(X)$ is $-\frac{1}{2}z^2$. From there, I make the substitution $u = z^2$ and proceed with the transformed PDF.

Comment: Yes, or you could use $u = \frac{x^2}{2 \sigma}$ if you wanted to make the exponential part $e^{-u}$ in one step.